# Most suitable particle-tracking software

Tags: software, multiphysics, particle

I have a problem for which I am trying to determine the most suitable software to use. Here is a brief description of the problem.

I have a mixture of inertial particles A and B with different properties. I want to inject this mixture into a channel filled with fluid, and observe the transport properties. I expect inter-particle collisions and two-way coupling between fluid and particles to be important to the physics we want to capture. I would also like to use non-Newtonian fluids.

I am looking for suggestions for commercial or open-source softwares that can tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you wish to model the two-way coupled solid-fluid flows or you wish to carry out PIV or tracking on particle images?
If you wish to model the two-way coupled solid-fluid flows, there are numerous type of models are that valid, most notably Euler-Euler approaches or Euler-Lagrange (CFD-DEM unresolved or resolved) approaches. Euler-Euler approaches are available in numerous open source (OpenFOAM) or commercial (Fluent, Star-CMM+) software.

For CFD-DEM modeling you can look at the following open source project:

- CFDEM project

(https://www.cfdem.com/), i was a developer of it during my thesis

Some commercial software are also incredibly powerful for these type of CFD-DEM problems:

- Fluent + EDEM
- Fluent + Rocky 4
- Star CCM+

Comment: I will look into these. I also obtained a suggestion to use MFIX(https://mfix.netl.doe.gov/). Do you have any suggestions on using MFIX vs using CFDEM workbench?

Comment: I am a little bit biased, because I have developed in the CFDEM framework. I think it depends on what you wish to do. If you want to study gas-solid flows, with chemical reaction, with chemical species and in the context of chemical processes, then MFIX is a lot better. However, I don't think it contains a lot for solid-liquid flows (and even less for complex rheology). I think the CFDEM framework is a bit more versatile in general, since it can benefit from all that comes with OpenFOAM, such as the support for non-newtonian fluid. However, the learning curve for both can be high.